# mapreduce between consecutive documents

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

**Setup:**

I got a large collection with the following entries

```
Name - String 
Begin - time stamp
End - time stamp
```

**Problem:**

I want to get the gaps between documents, Using the map-reduce paradigm.

**Approach:**

I'm trying to set a new collection of pairs `mid`, after that I can compute differences from it using `$unwind` and `Pair[1].Begin - Pair[0].End`

```
function map(){
    emit(0, this)
}
function reduce(){
    var i = 0;
    var pairs = [];
    while ( i < values.length -1){
        pairs.push([values[i], values[i+1]]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return {"pairs":pairs};
}
db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, sort:{begin:1}, out:{replace:"mid"})
```

This works with limited number of document because of the 16MB document cap. I'm not sure if I need to get the collection into memory and doing it there, How else can I approach this problem?

Comment: Don't get the point. Everything in the collection or "query" will be emitted with the same "0" key value. If you also read the [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) documentation properly then you should see how this fails in a very basic way. You cannot return a different data structure from your "reduce" than you do from "map". Perhaps you should explain your "intent" along with the code you are trying that does not work.

Comment: @NeilLunn I want to emit "pairs" so I can iterate them in a following MapReduce. the "0" key is to get all document to `reduce` function where they brake into pairs. I know this does not comply with the documentation but I can't think of a another way to produce it.

Comment: I get your intent in that. But the approach is wrong, and is actually quite simple really when you consider the available documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapReduce function of MongoDB has a different way of handling what you propose than the method you are using to solve it. The key factor here is "keeping" the "previous" document in order to make the comparison to the next.

The actual mechanism that supports this is the "scope" functionality, which allows a sort of "global" variable approach to use in the overall code. As you will see, what you are asking when that is considered takes no "reduction" at all as there is no "grouping", just emission of document "pair" data:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        if ( last == null ) {
           last = this;
        } else {
            emit( 
                {
                    "start_id": last._id,
                    "end_id": this._id
                },
                this.Begin - last.End
            );
            last = this;
        }
    },
    function() {}, // no reduction required
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
        "scope": { "last": null }
    }
)
```

Out with a collection as the output as required to your size.

But this way by using a "global" to keep the last document then the code is both simple and efficient.

Comment: @shevski The link already given in the answer tells you that variables declared there are "globals" which actually apply in "global" scope over all of "map"/"reduce" and "finalize" stages where required.

Comment: Map/Reduce with only a map() stage would be better written as a find() query and iterated via application code. For predictably on "consecutive" documents there also needs to be a defined sort order.

Comment: @Stennie Generally agreeable except that most people asking are looking for some way for this to occur on the server rather than with client interaction. Which I would believe was actually something I said on the very last mapReduce tagged question I answered just a few hours ago. I answer in context of what is asked.

Comment: @NeilLunn You need to advance `last` inside the `else` statement after `emit`.